# How to execute Ajax code when I click on the link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I can't figure out where the problem is :

here is the script :

```
<script>
$(".icross").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var obj = $(this);

    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "supprimer.php",
     data: 'id=' + obj.attr('rel')



success: function(html){  

},

});
</script>
```

and here is the html code associated :

```
<a href="#" class="icross" title="Supprimer" rel="80"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

I want ajax to execute supprimer.php?id=80 when I click on the link but it doesn't work.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a comma after `data: 'id=' + obj.attr('rel')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma after this line:

```
data: 'id=' + obj.attr('rel'),
                             ^
```

Also, if you don't have your script tag appearing after the element then you need a DOM ready wrapper:

```
$(function(){
    // code here
});
```

---

Side note: unless you have good reason to, I recommend using a data object instead of concatenating like that, because by passing an object, jQuery will handle the URL encoding for you.

```
data: { id: obj.attr('rel') },
```

Comment: Commas at the end of an object or array are allowed and ignored (except by ancient versions of IE).